# Right click on element leads to new page unable to inspect the element

Tags: selenium

I am facing a strange issue while identifying the element on one of the webpages in my application. There are links on the page and I need to click those links and perform the necessary steps.
When I right click on those links then it immediately takes me to that page, I am not able to inspect that link element. When I use inspect tool tip and mouse over any of the link then it highlights a big window where all the links are located and in the elements section nothing shows up, at least I thought I will find those links in view source. Any help is greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFb41.png)

Answer (score 0):

just press `ctrl+shift+i`

to open the inspect tool , sometime website will have event listeners for right mouse click to some other tasks . IN such case you can open dev tool using this short cut